# Merge Queue LinkedList

Tags: java

I have made a Queue with LinkedList and i want to make a method that merge this that call that method with the parametre of this method , i create a deep copy for one Queue but when i try then to merge this copy Queue i can not insert elements , but when this method called from anaother that it does not a copy it works correct.

```
QueueLinkedList
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Queue myQueue = new Queue();
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Alice",0));
        myQueue.remove();
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Alice",0));
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Bob", 2));
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Charlie", 2));

        Queue yourQueue = new Queue(myQueue);

        Queue herQueue = new Queue();
        herQueue.insert(new Person("Alice",1));
        yourQueue.merge(herQueue);
        System.out.println(yourQueue) ;
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Thodoris", 11));
        myQueue.insert(new Person("Dimitris", 24));
        yourQueue.remove() ;
        System.out.println(myQueue) ;
        System.out.println(yourQueue) ;

        if (yourQueue.equals(myQueue)){
            System.out.println("The two queues are the same");
        }else{
            System.out.println("The two queues are different");
        }
        System.out.println("My queue has " + myQueue.size() + " elements");
        while (!myQueue.isEmpty()){
            myQueue.remove();
        }
        Person p = myQueue.remove();
    }
}
class Queue
{
    private PersonQueueElement head ;
    private PersonQueueElement tail ;
    private int size = 0;

    public Queue()
    {
        head = null ;
        tail = null ;
        size = 0;
    }

    public Queue(Queue other)
    {
        if(other.head != null)
        {
            PersonQueueElement head = new PersonQueueElement(other.head);
            this.head = head ;
        }
        if(other.tail != null)
        {
            PersonQueueElement tail = new PersonQueueElement(other.tail);
            this.tail = tail ;
        }

        this.size = other.size ;

    }

    public void insert(Person value)
    {
        PersonQueueElement element = new PersonQueueElement(value);
        if(head == null)
        {
            tail = element ;
            head = tail ;
            size ++ ;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.setNext(element)  ;
            tail = tail.getNext();
            size ++ ;
        }
    }

    public Person remove()
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("The Queue is empty.") ;
            return null ;
        }
        else 
        {
            Person temp = head.getValue() ;
            head = head.getNext() ;
            size -- ;
            return temp;

        }
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        String result = "" ;
        PersonQueueElement current = head ;
        while(current != null)
        {
            result += current.getValue().toString() + " " ;
            current = current.getNext() ;
        }

        return "Queue: " + result ;
    }

    public boolean equals(Queue other)
    {
        Queue otherQueue = other ;
        if(size() != otherQueue.size())
        {
            return false ;
        }
        PersonQueueElement position = head ;
        PersonQueueElement otherPosition = otherQueue.head ;
        while(position != null)
        {
            if(!(position.getValue().equals(otherPosition.getValue())))
            {
                return false ;
            }

            position = position.getNext() ;
            otherPosition = otherPosition.getNext() ;
        }
        return true ;
    }

    public Queue merge(Queue other)
    {
        Queue mergeQueue = this ;
        PersonQueueElement position = other.head ;
        while(position != null)
        {
            mergeQueue.insert(new Person(position.getValue())) ;
            position = position.getNext() ;
        }
        return mergeQueue;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head == null ;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return size ;
    }
}
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private int AM;

    public Person(String name, int AM)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.AM = AM;
    }

    public Person(Person other)
    {
        this.name = other.name ;
        this.AM = other.AM ;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "(" + name + "," + AM + ")" ;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name ;
    }

    public int getAM()
    {
        return AM ;
    }
}
class PersonQueueElement
{
    private Person value ;
    private PersonQueueElement next ;

    public PersonQueueElement(Person value)
    {
        this.value = value ;
    }

    public PersonQueueElement(PersonQueueElement other)
    {
        if(other.value != null)
        {
            Person value = new Person(other.value) ;
            this.value = value ;
        }

        if(other.next != null)
        {
            PersonQueueElement next = new PersonQueueElement(other.next) ;
            this.next = next ;
        }

    }

    public void setNext(PersonQueueElement element)
    {
        next = element ;
    }

    public PersonQueueElement getNext()
    {
        return next ;
    }

    public Person getValue()
    {
        return value ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: No , the problem is logical maybe in deep copy the merge does not appear the correct results

Comment: is `merge` supposed to append to `this`? Also: what does your program do currently and waht is it supposed to do? What means "working correctly"?

Comment: I mean that if i have the Queues A = 1 ,2 ,3  , C = 4 i copy the A to another Queue and i make a deep copy so B = 1,2,3 but B.merge(C) appears 1,2,3 but it should appear 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in `Queue(Queue other)`

specifically this line

```
PersonQueueElement tail = new PersonQueueElement(other.tail);
```

The way it is currently implemented, you cannot create a new node you have to use the existing tail.

```
PersonQueueElement tail = other.tail;
```

Incidentally this constructor does not do a `deep` copy.
I suspect what you really want to do is insert all the elements from the original queue.

Something like:

```
public Queue(Queue other){

    if(other != null){
        PersonQueueElement node = other.head;
        while(node != null){
            this.insert(node.getValue());
            node =node.getNext();
        }
    }

}
```

this code yielded

`Queue: (Alice,0) (Bob,2) (Charlie,2) (Alice,1)
Queue: (Alice,0) (Bob,2) (Charlie,2) (Thodoris,11) (Dimitris,24) 
Queue: (Bob,2) (Charlie,2) (Alice,1) 
The two queues are different
My queue has 5 elements
The Queue is empty.`

Comment: Yes i want to have a same Queue but when i change the copy or the original the other will not change